# Insert statements aren't working in MYSQL (FOREIGN KEY)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hello I am getting this error and can't figure out how to fix it, anyone know how I should go about fixing this so my insert statement will work?

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "fk_person_fatherID"

I'm assuming its because the foreign keys work off the primary key and in the insert statements im declaring them before they are made? I could be completely off, please help (:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
persID           INT IDENTITY(1,1),
persFName        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
persLName        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
persGender       CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
persDOB          DATE NOT NULL,
persDOD          DATE ,
fatherID         INT ,
motherID         INT ,

CONSTRAINT pk_person_persID PRIMARY KEY(persID),
CONSTRAINT fk_person_fatherID FOREIGN KEY (fatherID) REFERENCES person(persID),
CONSTRAINT fk_person_motherID FOREIGN KEY (motherID) REFERENCES person(persID),
```

And this is my insert statement I have.

```
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID)
    VALUES ('Abraham', 'Simpson', 'M', '1994-01-15', '2015-07-21',NULL,NULL),
     ('Mona', 'Simpson', 'F', '1946-09-22', NULL,NULL,NULL),
     ( 'Herb', 'Simpson', 'M', '1963-11-21',NULL,1,2),
     ( 'Homer', 'Simpson', 'M', '1965-05-19',NULL,1,2),
     ( 'Clancy', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1945-02-12',NULL,NULL,NULL),
     ( 'Jackie', 'Bouvier', 'M', '1945-12-01','2016-05-15',NULL,NULL),
     ( 'Marge', 'Simpson', 'F', '1966-05-18',NULL,6,5),
     ( 'Patty', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1964-01-08',NULL,6,5),
     ( 'Selma', 'Bouvier', 'F', '1969-03-01',NULL,6,5),
     ( 'Bart', 'Simpson', 'M', '1990-01-01',NULL,4,7),
     ( 'Lisa', 'Simpson', 'F', '1992-05-15',NULL,4,7),
     ( 'Maggie', 'Simpson', 'F', '1997-11-28',NULL,4,7),
     ( 'Ling', 'Bouvier', 'M', '2000-04-02',NULL,NULL,9)
```

Comment: @raina77ow Why is that a problem?

Comment: @raina77ow, but fatherID column is nullable. It doesn't cause the constrait foreign key problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the error message is pretty clear.

```
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD,fatherID,motherID)
     ( 'Herb', 'Simpson', 'M', '1963-11-21',NULL,1,2)
     ( 'Homer', 'Simpson', 'M', '1965-05-19',NULL,1,2)
```

You are trying to set `FatherId` value as 1 but I think there is no record with Id 1 in `person` table

Comment: This seems like the most likely explanation +1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by taking out the mother and father ID'S

```
INSERT INTO person(persFName,persLname,persGender,persDOB,persDOD)
    VALUES ('Abraham', 'Simpson', 'M', '1994-01-15', '2015-07-21'),
     ('Mona', 'Simpson', 'F', '1946-09-22', NULL),
     ( 'Herb', 'Simpson', 'M', '1963-11-21',NULL),
     ( 'Homer', 'Simpson', 'M', '1965-05-19',NULL),
```

And to add into the mother and father ID's I ended up just going to "Edit Top 200 Rows" and manually put in the ID's after I added the input statement